# jQuery validation: display the focused field error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

**Objective**: I'd like to display the focused field error message in a container.

**What I've done so far**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            label.pre {
                display:inline-block;
                width:60px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("form").validate({
                    messages: {
                        name: "Please specify your name.",
                        email: {
                            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
                            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
                        },
                        url: "A valid URL, please.",
                        comment: "Please enter your comment."
                    },
                    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                        if (errorList.length) {
                            $("span").html(errorList[0].message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<span></span>
        <form action="#">
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_0">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="required" name="name" id="entry_0">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_1">Email *</label>
                <input type="text" class="required email" name="email"
                id="entry_1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_2">URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="url" name="url" id="entry_2">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea class="required" name="comment" id="entry_3" rows="7" cols="35"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/32hje/

**Problems**:

1. If you click the submit button, the container(span) shows the first
   error message, no matter which field was focused.
2. Focusing on fields using the Tab key works well (except on the URL field), but focusing with a mouse doesn't update the span HTML correctly.

Comment: have u load the css.... and not sure why are u using span to display error..since  jquery validation does that by itself.. it creates the error container (label.error), if there is any error

Comment: @bipen: "not sure why are u using span to display error" To display only one error message -- the one related to the focused field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! I just re-checked the [validate options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) and realized I should have used `errorPlacement` instead of `showErrors`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            label.pre {
                display:inline-block;
                width:60px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("form").validate({
                    messages: {
                        name: "Please specify your name.",
                        email: {
                            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
                            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
                        },
                        url: "A valid URL, please.",
                        comment: "Please enter your comment."
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        element.focus(function () {
                            $("span").html(error);
                        }).blur(function () {
                            $("span").html('');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
<span></span>
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_0">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="required" name="name" id="entry_0">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_1">Email *</label>
                <input type="text" class="required email" name="email"
                id="entry_1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="pre" for="entry_2">URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="url" name="url" id="entry_2">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea class="required" name="comment" id="entry_3" rows="7" cols="35"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 1:

> the container(span) shows the first error message, no matter which
>   field was focused.

That's just because you had hard coded `errorList[0].message` to the span html

For problem number 2:

> Focusing on fields using the Tab key works well, but focusing with a
>   mouse doesn't update the span HTML correctly.

Here's a suggested variation of your code, it will give a running list of errors when you try to submit, or as you tab/click on/off fields it should show issue (if any), though the behavior varies slightly based on tabbing through or clicking, hope it helps or gets you on right track

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate({
        messages: {
            name: "Please specify your name.",
            email: {
                required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
            },
            url: "A valid URL, please.",
            comment: "Please enter your comment."
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            var msg = 'Errors: ';
            $.each(errorList, function(){
                 msg += this.message + '<br />'; });

            $("span").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "That's just because you had hard coded errorList[0].message to the span html" I wonder how to get the focused field error message and display it.***"it will give a running list of errors when you try to submit" it's not what I'm looking for -- as I said and seen on the demo I'd like to display only the focused field error message.

Comment: I played around with your snippet and created the following:[modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ccZye/2/). Everything seems alright to me, but it still doesn't work well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

this fixes prob no. 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").validate({
        messages: {
            name: "Please specify your name.",
            email: {
                required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
            },
            url: "A valid URL, please.",
            comment: "Please enter your comment."
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            if (errorList.length) {
                $("span").html(errorList[0].message);
            }
        }
    });
    $("form input").focus(function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });
```

Comment: On focus, it displays an error message initially even if the user hasn't made any mistake.